# insert into statament java jstl tag

Tags: sql, jsp, session, servlets, jstl

```
    <sql:update dataSource="${applicationScope.oracleDataSource}"
        var="count">
        
        insert into books(ID,TITLE,AUTHOR,PRICE) where=user_id = <c:out value='${sessionScope.userID}'/> values(book_id_seq.nextval,title,author,price) 
        <sql:param value="${param.title}" />
        <sql:param value="${param.author}" />
        <sql:param value="${param.price}" />
    </sql:update>
```

I have books tables. I also have the users table. I want to register their own books for each logged in user. However, I could not write the necessary query to save the book.I would be grateful if you could help with the correct query.

Comment: JSTL's `<sql:...>` (and `<x:...>`) tags are officially discouraged since 2001 because they only encourage bad practices. Do not use them. Use normal Java code instead (JDBC or JPA).

Comment: Using JSTL to connect to database from the front is not secured, and also discouraged since 2001, try to connect and get data from backend side, as BalusC mentioned above JDBC of JPA Hibernate.